# MYSQL, JOIN, AS, LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have very limited to zero knowledge about SQL or DBs, so apologies in advance.

I am attempting to make a table like structure within a webpage, a column for meal name, and a column for ingredients - it is also searchable via a button.

EDIT:

Thanks for all the replies, they have been most helpful.
The error no longer happens, however now I get no results from the database, but no error.

```
include("inc/dbConn.php"); /////$db_conx

if(isset($_POST["search"])){   
    $searchq = $_POST["search"];
    $sql ="
           SELECT main_meal.name, ingred.name
           FROM main_meal
           JOIN meal_ingred on meal_ingred.meal_id = main_meal.id
           JOIN ingred ON ingred.id = meal_ingred.ingred_id
           WHERE ingred.name LIKE '%$searchq%'";
    $results = $db_conx->query($sql);   
    var_dump($results);
    if($results->num_rows){

        while ($row =$results->fetch_object()){
            echo "{$row->name} ({$row->name})<br>";

        }     
    }    
}
```

For clarification here is my structure:

(Sorry for external link, I dont have enough reputation to post images.)

http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c340/Tyrage/Untitled-2_zpsc48126b3.png

The $results dumps:

**object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }**

It is quite obvious I don't have a clue what I am doing, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified your query is correct? You have an alias on your join table, instead of a join column. You are also not defining what to join between `main_meal` and `ingred`, but doing a `LIKE` on the `ingred` table only. Your query is failing so `$result` is a non-object, which you can't then use `->fetch_object()`.

Comment: Use `var_dump($results)` to see whether `FALSE` is being returned. That would indicate an error. More information here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM main_meal
JOIN meal_ingred ON meal_ingred.meal_id = main_meal.id
JOIN ingred ON meal_ingred.meal_id = main_meal.id
WHERE ingred.ingredName LIKE  '%bread%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

with the php as follow:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["search"])){
    $searchq = $_POST["search"];
    $sql ="
        SELECT * 
FROM main_meal
JOIN meal_ingred ON meal_ingred.meal_id = main_meal.id
JOIN ingred ON meal_ingred.meal_id = main_meal.id
WHERE ingred.ingredName LIKE  '%$searchq%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
          ";
    //$results = $db_conx->query($sql);
    if (!$results = $db_conx->query($sql)) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", $db_conx->error);
    }
    $count = $results->num_rows;

    if($count > 0){
        while($row=$results->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row['ingredName'];
            echo $row['name'] . "<br />";
            $output="ff";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you're lacking a relation table here, which will store connection between meals and ingredients.

also you had error in your query because at first you've tried to use a/b naming correctly, to name a column, and then you user it to name a table.

IMHO you should do something like this (with relation table added):

```
if(isset($_POST["search"])){   
    $searchq = $_POST["search"];
    $sql ="
           SELECT main_meal.name AS a, ingred.name as b
           FROM main_meal 
           JOIN rel_meal_ingred on rel_meal_ingred.meal_id = main_meal.id
           JOIN ingred ON ingred.id =  rel_meal_ingred.ingred_id
           where ingred.name LIKE '%$searchq%'";

    $results = $db_conx->query($sql);   

       if($results->num_rows){ //////line 15
       while ($row =$results->fetch_object()){
       echo "{$row->a} ({$row->b})<br>";

       }       
       }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Line numbers would help, to see if line 15 is the assignment to $results, or if line 15 is the $results->num_rows

I'm also assuming you have a $db_conx->connect command somewhere in your code, to open the database connection before running the query?

Comment: Ah sorry yes lack of detail on my part.

 if($results->num_rows){ is line 15.

And yes there is an includes with a connection to the database above.

Comment: To see the actual query error, check this function before using the results variable. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query is invalid: there is no such column as `ingred.name` available in the WHERE clause, because you have renamed that table as `b`.

There is no reason to rename your tables (using `AS ...`) in this query. Leave that clause out. Then add a join condition (e.g, `... JOIN ingred ON (...)` — omitting this will make the query return every row from `main_meal`.

Additionally, there is probably a SQL injection vulnerability in your code, because you are interpolating the contents of the (likely unfiltered) `$searchq` variable into the query. Use a query placeholder for the argument to `LIKE`.